# Update WooCommerce order status via WooCommerce callback

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I created a custom payment gateway plugin that caters payment for WooCommerce site orders via a third party payment gateway. Once the third party received the payment of the customer it then sends post data into your designated URL so you can process/update your database. Updating order status on WooCommerce callback via Get method works but not with Post.

This what i am working with

```
        add_action( 'woocommerce_api_callback', array( $this, 'thirdparty_response' ));  


        function thirdparty_response()
        {  
           global $woocommerce;

           if(isset($_POST['order_id']) && isset($_POST['order_status'])) //Parameters sent by third party gateway
           {
               $order_status = $_POST['order_status'];
               $order_id = $_POST['order_id'];
               $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

               if ($order_status == "success") 
               {
                  $order->update_status('processing', __('Payment Received', 'woothemes'));
               }
               else
               {
                  $order->update_status('failed', __('Payment Failed', 'woothemes'));
               }

           }

        }
```

Thank you and I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created your Gateway class? This is a snippet from WC Paypal Gateway, and to activate the check_response you have to configure your 3rd party Payment Gateway service to callback your URL formed like this (you need to replace the name of your class in both callback URL and in the hook name):

```
$your_callback = str_replace( 'https:', 'http:', add_query_arg( 'wc-api', 'WC_Gateway_Paypal', home_url( '/' ) ) );

public function __construct( $sandbox = false, $receiver_email = '' ) {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_api_wc_gateway_paypal', array( $this, 'check_response' ) );
        add_action( 'valid-paypal-standard-ipn-request', array( $this, 'valid_response' ) );

        $this->receiver_email = $receiver_email;
        $this->sandbox        = $sandbox;
    }
```